# Limit the number of characters in input of type number

Tags: html, angular

I am using angular material with reactive form where i have an input field of type number. I want to limit the value that user can enter in the textbox from 1 to 99. I am able to achieve this but i see the value for a fraction of seconds after key up and then the value is sliced as i have written the slice logic inside the keyup event. I tried writing this logic in keypress but it does not seem to work. I tried using event.stopPropogation() and preventDefault but no luck. Below is the code:

```
<input type="number"
          matInput
          min="1"
          max="99"
          #tempVar
          autocomplete="off"
          formControlName="noOfWeeks"
          (keyup)="imposeMinMax(tempVar)"
          (keypress)="numericOnly($event)"
        />
```

**TS File**

```
  numericOnly(e): boolean {
   return e.keyCode === 8 && e.keyCode === 46 
   ? true
   : !isNaN(Number(e.key));
  }

  imposeMinMax(el) {
      if (
        el.value != '' &&
        (parseInt(el.value) < parseInt(el.min) ||
          parseInt(el.value) > parseInt(el.max))
      ) {
          el.value = el.value.toString().slice(0, 2);
        }
      }
```

Comment: **keypress: Deprecated**
This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

Comment: You could create a directive, would be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest an approach, that makes use of the `keydown` event:

```
    <input type="number"
              matInput
              min="1"
              max="99"
              #tempVar
              autocomplete="off"
              formControlName="noOfWeeks"
              (keydown)="handleKeydown($event)"
            />
```

```
handleKeyDown(e) {
    const typedValue = e.keyCode;
    if (typedValue < 48 && typedValue > 57) {
      // If the value is not a number, we skip the min/max comparison 
      return;
    }

    const typedNumber = parseInt(e.key);
    const min = parseInt(e.target.min);
    const max = parseInt(e.target.max);
    const currentVal = parseInt(e.target.value) || '';
    const newVal = parseInt(typedNumber.toString() + currentVal.toString());

    if (newVal < min || newVal > max) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
```

Certainly, this `handleKeyDown` method can be further extended, depending on your requirement.